# How (and is it even possible) to change values for the Config system files?

Tags: node.js, config

I am using the config.json for the 1st time. from the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

Besides the Server Url's , id,password and all other Constants, I want to store there a query **but** I would like to have an opportunity to change some of the parameters in it:

```
"queryExample": {
    "interval": "",
    "order": "desc",
    "paging": {
        "pageSize": 100,
        "pageNumber": 1
    }
}
```

In this case I will need to set the values for the **interval** and then, when paginating, **increment the pageNumber**.

I've tried :

```
let query = config.get("queryExample");
    query.interval = interval;
    console.log(query);
```

as well as :

```
let query = config.queryExample;
    config.queryExample.interval = interval;
    console.log(config.agentsQuery);
```

in multiple variations but I cannot make the interval appear.

I am sure that interval arrives to the function.

Should my solution be rather create a local variable in the code and change pageNumber interval etc there or Is there a way to change it in .config/default. json?

Please help :_|

Comment: What's "the config.json"? Are you using a configuration library / package from npm? If so, which one?

Comment: @robert HI thank you for the comment this is actually very important , true . I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/config npm package that requires creating a config folder and then the default/prod etc file in it

Comment: up.............

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your config file as `/config/default.json`. Config has a few "opinions" on the naming and placement of your config file. Y [Read more here](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files)

Comment: Hey. I think  you didn't get the question. I was asking actually if the data in config is considered as const or var ? basically . Cause i need to re-use the same query but increment the pageNumber